# Gradle sync failed: Could not create task ':app:lintFix'

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I just installed Android Studio v4.1.2 but whenever I try to create a new project then it gives me the following error:

> Could not create task ':app:lintFix'.
> Could not create task of type 'LintFixTask'.
> Could not generate a decorated class for type LintFixTask.
> com/android/tools/lint/gradle/api/LintExecutionRequest
> com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.LintExecutionRequest

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the root cause of the problem but as it's your first project & fresh installation, I suggest you try this :

Link to fresh new folder: https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/921571/MyApplicationtoresolveissueswithfirsttimeprojectcreationinandroidstudio.zip

I've created fresh new project in my Android studio I am sharing the zip file with you after the gradle build was successfully finished.
Now I recommend that you download this and open it as a fresh new project using your Android studio as it is a successful project so it might give you the pop ups to take necessary actions and might resolve your issue.
Let me know if it helps.